# When I navigate to the view controller containing ARSCNView a blank screen appears

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I navigate to the view controller containing `ARSCNView` a blank screen appears instead of camera view, with all other `UI` Elements visible partially (transparent)

This is my code for navigating to the next `ViewController`

let

```
secondViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
self.present(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since ARSCNView uses camera you have to add permission request in plist file. Add "Privacy - Camera Usage Description" in order to be able to use camera.